# Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-context

Code for reference (without navigation and signup button):
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sound-djldko?file=/src/components/Auth.js

I am getting the following error, Unable to spot the error.

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

**CODE:**

```
import React from "react"
import { auth } from "../services/Auth"

export const UserContext = React.createContext()

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState()

React.useEffect(()=>{
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(setUser);
},[])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useCurrentUser = () => React.useContext(UserContext)
```

Comment: AFAIT, There shouldn't be such an error in this snippet.

Comment: Javascript errors in Google Chrome's console tell you the line number and file that generated the error. Look at that line

Comment: maybe initialize your state with  an empty object `React.useState({})` So it wont be undefined while waiting for auth.onAuthStateChanged to finish up.

Comment: Did that too..but struck no luck...it throws the same error

Comment: What are you setting the user as in setUser ?

Comment: I have edited the questions with the link to code

Comment: Are you getting pop up of google? Is data going inside firebase? And check what output are you getting after 
`
    const qry = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
    const docs = await getDocs(qry);
`
check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries